# How to get ondetached event for a dialog fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've a situation like from my fragment activity, I need to do some operations when the fragment got detached from the fragment activity.

I know I can check for isDetached(), but i need to call some operations when the fragment got detached. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an interface in your Dialog Fragment that your activity must implement. In your Dialog Fragment you can override the "onDetach" method and call the listener activity in that method.

So something along these lines:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    public interface CallBack{
       public void onMyDialogFragmentDetached();
    }

    public CallBack mCallBack;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
       super.onAttach(activity);
       mCallBack = (CallBack) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach(){
       super.onDetach();
       mCallBack.onMyDialogFragmentDetached();
    }

}
```

Then just have your activity implement MyDialogFragment.CallBack:

```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyDialogFragment.CallBack{

    @Override
    public void onMyDialogFragmentDetached(){
       /** Called When MyDialogFragment gets detached. */
    }

  }
```

I hope that helps. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is I'm having so many fragments and so overriding onDetach in every fragment is not possible for me. Also I cannot create a base class for fragment so that I can do the same, but then also I need to change the inheritance for all the current fragments. So is there any way to hook to fragments onDetach from outside?